# Sitefinity 12.2 MVC- Add functionality to toolbar

Tags: model-view-controller, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, sitefinity

I would like to be able to add a "button" style option to the kendo toolbar in sitefinity contentblock.

I am running v 12.2 MVC.

I created the project, created my resource package under resource packages, cloned sf-html-field.sf-cshtml and placed in ResourcePackages/mycustompackage/client-components/fields/html-field/ and as a test I deleted the Bold option. Note: The template I am using is based on one under my resource package in MVC/Views/Layouts. - It did not change the toolbar in the content block. I also changed it under the Bootstrap4 folder, and in addition I created /client-components/fields/html-field/ in the root and added the sf-html-field.sf-cshtml there and still no luck in making Bold disappear. I have also tried including the js file present in the frontend feather git repository.

I have also found a config.json file under AdminApp that had values for the toolbar and removed bold, but it still did not disappear from the toolbar.

I have also tried creating the ContentBlock under ResourcePackages/mycustompackage/MVC/Views/ContentBlock, included the designerview.contentblock.json with the priority, and still no luck.

I have tried rebuilding the project, restarting the app. Any help would be much appreciated. Links where I have looked for documentation include

https://github.com/Sitefinity/mvc-samples/tree/master/CustomStylesContentBlock
https://github.com/Sitefinity/mvc-samples/tree/master/SimpleContentBlock
https://www.progress.com/documentation/sitefinity-cms/extend-the-html-field-of-the-rich-text-editor
https://github.com/Sitefinity/feather-widgets/issues/1240
https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/mvc-link-selector-anchor-for-internal-pages

Answer (score 0):

By following the instructions on https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/mvc-link-selector-anchor-for-internal-pages I was able to edit the link selector to add a checkbox to add the button class if selected. This works within Design > Page templates > my custom template > content block widget.

Sadly, it does not change the link selector within Pages > Home (uses my custom template) and I also noticed that the kendo editor for the content blocks within the page template is different than the editor for the content blocks within the pages. VERY frustrating! Can anyone shed some light on this?

Update: Ok apparently this has to do with the New vs Classic experience. By turning off the New experience I am able to see the same toolbar that I see in the Page Templates editor. This is an awful experience, because I cant use some of the new features that the new experience has if I want to have a full toolbar available. Anyone have any idea how to edit the New experience toolbar & link selector?

Answer (score 0):

So locally if I put the client-components folder on my root it all worked. If I put it to my live site in the root it wouldn't work. My site is also using the bootstrap 4 so I tried pushing it there and it didn't work and I was confused. I tried putting the file under the ResourcePackages\bootstrap folder and it worked. Which makes no sense because I'm using Bootstrap 4 for everything else. But I am on 12.0 Maybe it's a bug? But try that and see if you resolve your issue.

Comment: Thanks. I tried both in the root and created a Bootstrap folder under ResourcePackages and dropped my custom client components in there. I turned the New Interface on, cleared cache, restarted IIS and still my custom client components dont appear in the kendo editable regions. They still only work if the new interface is turned off, which is frustrating because with the old interface it appears content blocks use Kendo while module rich text areas use RadEditor...